# Are there published specs for Google API bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I am developing a Google APP Engine or possibly just direct GCS application. The client captures video streams from cameras and would like to selectively stream these to the cloud.

Possible targets are:

- A Google App Engine app
- Google Cloud Storage (JSON)
- Google Drive API
- Google Hangouts (incl. Hangouts on Air)

When considering the different architecture choices (which all have great features), we need to know what the max rate is for uploading.

Maybe this is a very naive question and the rate is "faster than you can give is data". If so, then that's all I need to know, and that's excellent. But if not, I'd love to have some idea of the throughput capabilities for a single connected client.

Is that a reasonable question? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is relevant:

1. HD video streams come in at [about 4-8 Mbit/s](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-bandwidth-requirement-to-stream-a-1080p-HD-movie-off-a-remote-server). I'm pretty sure any of those services can handle that.
2. Google services (AppEngine, Drive, etc..) support hundreds of millions of users. A few users of yours do not make a difference in overall performance.
3. None of those services does true video streaming - it's all file upload and after it's finished other clients can start downloading it.
4. Afaik Hangouts do not expose low-level video API. User needs to use their plugin to use Hangouts. Meaning you can not upload your video directly.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your insights!

Comment: I was really hoping for an authoritative answer from a Google staffer.  i'm aware of the scale of the Google services, I was primarily wondering if there is any throttling that goes on for an individual connection, or if there was an option for guaranteed QoS. I read a little bit about the 'Backends' service but it was not clear if this was  higher throughput guarantee or just a different pricing model for large volumes.

Comment: The important message is that none of those services does true real-time streaming. They only support file upload and the download. In this scenario it does not matter how fast the upload is.